# Optimize speed when comparing fields from one MongoDB to another

Tags: python, python-3.x, mongodb, pymongo, pymongo-3.x

I have two MongoDBs, one database `urls` is used by a spider that gathers URLs. This database is quite large, and mostly just contains urls. A second db, `posts`, is used by a program that scans the urls and generates a report based on the url.

The code I'm currently using for the second script checks if a url in the `urls` database is currently in the `posts` database. If the `posts` db does not contain the url it means the program still needs to generate a report for the url. If it exists, we skip it.

Here is the database loop:

```
for document in urls.find():
    url = document['url'].split('.')[1]

    if posts.find({'url': url}).count() == 0:
        print(url, " url not found in posts, generating a new report")

        try:
            get_report(url, posts)
        ...
```

At first this seemed like a simple solution. However, after the `posts` db was populated with over 50,000 reports, this loop takes hour(s) to begin.

Is there a faster / more efficient way to perform this loop? I'm using python3 with pymongo.

Additionally, the script is now crashing with a `pymongo.errors.CursorNotFound: cursor id '…'` error. I believe this means I need to set the batch size to a lower value. However, this is only re-enforcing my belief that something about this loop is extremely inefficient.

Comment: do you have an index on the url in the posts db

Comment: I have not created an index besides the auto-generated ids

Comment: try `db.posts.createIndex( { url : 1 } )` on your db and see if the query is any faster

Comment: Is this a line I should add before starting the loop, or its something that only needs to be executed once?

Comment: Actually, url isn't assigned as a variable until inside the loop, did you mean ({ 'url' : 1})?

Comment: executed once on your db (through the mongo shell)

Comment: I think I did this correctly through pymongo, although I haven't noticed any increase in speed.

Comment: Can you share database schemas (structure of your collections) and also share complete code or atleast get_report function

Answer (score 3):

If `urls.find():` finds all of the documents in the collection and loops over them, it's inevitably going to slow down as the collection gets larger.

Can you mark your processed documents urls with processed `true` when you've seen it and created the necessary posts? That way, you can instead do `urls.find({processed: {$ne: true}})` to find only the urls that you need to process. With this scheme, you'd want to have an index on `{processed: 1}` on your url collection, and an index on `{url: 1}` for your posts collection.

Answer (score 1):

Iterate huge collections and search per document is *very expensive* for any database.

**Generic Solution**: Add some flag/mechanism to process only new URLs. (metioned by **@willis**)

**Solution 1:** Batch search (`$in`). If you search (lets say 100 urls per `find`), it will increase your program (x100):

```
db.posts.find({"url" : {"$in" : urls}})
*urls = [url1, url2, ..., url100]
```

Now, you need to check what `URL` doesn't exists in `posts`.

**Solution 2:** (Only if the same DB) Use [$lookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/). 
You need to add some indexes and it does the trick (MongoDB native implementation is more faster then manual).

**BTW:** Do you mean 2 different databases in (same|different) server or 2 collections in the same database?

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
urls = []
for document in urls.find():
    url = document['url'].split('.')[1]
    urls.append(url)

url_dict = {u:True for u in urls}

urls2 = posts.find({"url":1})

for url in urls2:
    if url not in url_dict.keys():

        print(url, " url not found in posts, generating a new report")

        try:
            get_report(url, posts)
        ...
```

This essentially load everything in memory. If you don't have enough memory, try to arbitrarily hash your urls and process one by one.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to put a cache in between, Redis sets will help.